# Configuration of Apache CXF CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter with Spring

Tags: java, spring, cors, jax-rs, cxf

How can I configure the Apache CXF [`CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter`](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/cxf/trunk/rt/rs/security/cors/src/main/java/org/apache/cxf/rs/security/cors/CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter.java) without changing the source code (annotated class or beans.xml)?

In the [JAX-RS: CORS example](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-cors.html#JAX-RSCORS-Examples) the configuration is hard-coded:

> Here is the test code showing how CrossOriginResourceSharing annotations can be applied at the resource and individual method levels.
>
> [...]
>
> ```
> @GET
> @CrossOriginResourceSharing(
>      allowOrigins = { "http://area51.mil:31415" }, 
>      allowCredentials = true, 
>      exposeHeaders = { "X-custom-3", "X-custom-4" }
> )
> @Produces("text/plain")
> @Path("/annotatedGet/{echo}")
> public String annotatedGet(@PathParam("echo") String echo) {
>     return echo;
> }
> ```

I use beans.xml to configure the `allowOrigins` property:

```
<bean id="cors-filter" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.cors.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter">
    <property name="allowOrigins">
        <list>
            <value>myserver1</value>
            <value>myserver2</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I thought I could get the property from JNDI, but it is not allowed to add a `List` (see [Servlet Specification 2.5](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/servlet-2.5-mrel2-eval-oth-JSpec/)). And I need a way to configure an empty `List` for CORS [`*`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header).

```
<bean id="cors-filter"
    class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.cors.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter">
    <property name="allowOrigins"><
        <jee:jndi-lookup jndi-name="CORS/origins"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

What is the intended/preferred way to configure the `CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter` in a reusable WAR?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you use some environment variable to set a comma separated list of origins like this:

```
<bean id="cors-filter"
    class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.cors.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter">
        <property name="allowOrigins" value="#{systemProperties['origins'] != null ? systemProperties['origins'].split(',') : null}"> 
    </property>
</bean>
```

- this is a tested code

And pass `-Dorigins=or1,or2,...` to JVM (or don't pass to get null value)

If you need to pass an empty list in configuration you can edit code like this (replace `null` with `{}` in property value):

```
<bean id="cors-filter"
    class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.cors.CrossOriginResourceSharingFilter">
         <property name="prop" value="#{systemProperties['test'] != null ? systemProperties['test'].split(',') : {}}">
         </property>
</bean>
```

this way,if you **don't** add -Dorigins to Java VM Options, an empty list will be used.

Based on [Spring EL Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-evaluation) you can use all object methods:

> As an example of method invocation, we call the 'concat' method on the string literal.
>   `Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("'Hello World'.concat('!')");`